# List View with Custom Simple Cursor adapter from DataBase (Sqlite) "unhandled event loop Exception"

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, sqlite

I try a Custom Simple Cursor adapter for Listview. I get datas from Database and try to show my listview But I got some exception. İf u help me I will so happy thanks. Here is code:

```
public class cursorDeneme extends ListActivity{
Cursor c ;
String sutunlar[]  = new String[]{"name"};
int to[] = new int[]{R.id.name_entry};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cursorden);
DB_E db = new DB_E(this);// database class

try {
    db.openReadable();

    c=db.veriAlCursor();// gets Cursor from database

    mySimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new mySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.cursorden, c, sutunlar, to);

    db.close();
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);


} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Here is database class:

```
 public class DB_E {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID ="id";
public static final String KEY_WORK_OUT ="workout"; //Hangi workout
public static final String KEY_NAME ="name";
public static final String KEY_REP ="rep";
public static final String KEY_WEIGHT ="weight";
    public Cursor veriAlCursor(){ //get datas

    Cursor c = ourDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, sutunlar, null, null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}
public Cursor veriAlCursor(String workout){ //get datas

workout ="'%"+workout+"%'";
    Cursor c = ourDataBase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, sutunlar, KEY_WORK_OUT+" LIKE "+workout, null, null, null, null);

    return c;
}
```

And mySimpleCustomAdapter:

```
public class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
Cursor c;
Context context;
Activity activity;
cursorDeneme cursorD ;
public mySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.c=c;
    this.activity=(Activity)context;
    this.context=context;
    this.cursorD =(cursorDeneme)context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent){

    if(convertView == null)
    convertView.inflate(context, R.layout.liste, null);

    View row=convertView;

    c.moveToPosition(position);
    int iName =c.getColumnIndex("name");
    TextView name =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
    name.setText(c.getString(iName));
    return (row);
}
```

and Xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#848484" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="#CEF6E3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#151515"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        ></ListView>
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Error log : Unhandled event loop Exception 
            Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax
            ...
Thanks.

Comment: this is not due to cursor it seems its adt problem same with me but when i run  the application it runs just fine

Comment: @Akki How to allow permission. log cat "Permission Denied"